# Unable to make field private in spring boot Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am trying to clone this project [Repos](https://github.com/sfg-beer-works/brewery-monolith)
It gives me this error
**java: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Unable to make field private com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoveredProcs accessible: module jdk.compiler does not "opens com.sun.tools.javac.processing" to unnamed module @27119bf**

I am Following this [Course](https://www.udemy.com/course/spring-boot-microservices-with-spring-cloud-beginner-to-guru/)
This is my POM.XML

````
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.github.sfg-beer-works</groupId>
        <artifactId>sfg-beer-works-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </parent>

<!--    <groupId>sfg.brewery</groupId>-->
    <artifactId>brewery-monolith</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <description>SFG Brewery Monolith UI</description>
    <name>SFG Brewery Monolith UI</name>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>GNU General Public License v3.0</name>
            <url>https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.txt</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <organization>
        <name>Spring Framework Guru</name>
    </organization>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <name>John Thompson</name>
            <organization>Spring Framework Guru</organization>
        </developer>
    </developers>
    
    <properties>
        <!-- Web dependencies -->
        <webjars-bootstrap.version>3.3.6</webjars-bootstrap.version>
        <webjars-jquery-ui.version>1.12.1</webjars-jquery-ui.version>
        <webjars-jquery.version>3.3.0</webjars-jquery.version>
        <wro4j.version>1.8.0</wro4j.version>
        <!--set this to your docker acct name-->
        <docker.image.prefix>sfgbeerworks</docker.image.prefix>
        <!--Set to name of project-->
        <docker.image.name>${artifactId}</docker.image.name>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- webjars -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-jquery.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-jquery-ui.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-bootstrap.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end of webjars -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${wro4j.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <wroManagerFactory>ro.isdc.wro.maven.plugin.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory
                    </wroManagerFactory>
                    <cssDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/classes/static/resources/css</cssDestinationFolder>
                    <wroFile>${basedir}/src/main/wro/wro.xml</wroFile>
                    <extraConfigFile>${basedir}/src/main/wro/wro.properties</extraConfigFile>
                    <contextFolder>${basedir}/src/main/less</contextFolder>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
                        <version>${webjars-bootstrap.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                        <version>2.23.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!--<dockerHost>http://127.0.0.1:2375</dockerHost>-->
                    <dockerHost>unix:///var/run/docker.sock</dockerHost>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <images>
                        <image>
                            <name>${docker.image.prefix}/${docker.image.name}</name>
                            <alias>brewery-ui</alias>
                            <build>
                                <!--copies artifact to docker build dir in target-->
                                <assembly>
                                    <descriptorRef>artifact</descriptorRef>
                                </assembly>
                                <dockerFile>Dockerfile</dockerFile>
                                <tags>
                                    <tag>latest</tag>
                                    <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                                </tags>
                            </build>
                        </image>
                    </images>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>```
````

Comment: If you would go down the error, there would be caused by: in the error log. Please add that to question also

Comment: It looks like the code provided is designed for Java 8 ... but you are using Java 9 or later.

Comment: Also, please mention which java version are you using?

Comment: I am using Java 16 and 11 specifically

Comment: @DRASHTI DOBARIYA there is no caused by in this error this simple gets resolved by changing java-version or spring boot version.

Answer (score 2):

This is related to mismatch of your Java version and lombok version please upgrade the lombok

Answer (score 0):

I  resolved this by changing java-version.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: It's related to lombok and its compatibility with the java version being used. The solution is to either upgrade to the latest lombok version or downgrade the java version if that's possible for you.